Need help reading data from ADS8678, 14bit A2D
I have a Raspberry PI connected to an ADS8678 (A2D) (datasheet here) and an AD5754 (DAC) via the primary SPI bus.

I'm using the pigpio lib to control the SPI bus, and it's working great for the DAC.
For the A2D, I'm running into a little trouble reading data from it.
As a 14bit converter, it should only output a max of 2^14 or 0x3FFF.  However, I'm getting readings like this when reading the same channel over and over:
0x8554, 0x8558, 0x855C

I'm sending the command to read channel 4, 0xD000, followed by 16 bits of zeros to clock out the data, per the datasheet.
I know the scope shows MISO for both screen shots, I only have a 2 channel scope.

For the Code:
// In the A2D Constructor I configure the SPI module and set the gain to 1.25
spi_ = new Spi( A2D_SPI_CHANNEL, SPI_MODE_1 );
setRange( RANGE_CH4, GAIN_1_25 );

// In the main loop I call this every 100ms
reg__ = CMD_MAN_Ch_4;
xfer( reg__, rxData.data());

Member function:
// write 16bits of command followed by 16bits of 0 to get the data
int A2d::xfer( uint32_t data, char *rxBuf )
{
// return spi_->xfer( txBuf, rxBuf, 3 );
// flip endian for SPI chip required order
data = htonl( data << 16 );

// copy to the class register array
memcpy( reg_, &data, sizeof( reg_ ) );

// 16 bits of command and 16 clocks to read data (32 total)
return spi_->xfer( (char *)reg_, rxBuf, 4 );
}

The data that ends up in the buffer rxData.data matches what the scope is showing, so I know it's not an endian issue.
The SPI peripheral is configured in Mode 1, falling clock edge to read data (per the datasheet).
I've also tried reading the other channels in AUTO_RST mode and I get similar results, like 0x8ac4 for about 2.5V on the other channels.
I don't understand why the data from the A2D is greater than 0x3fff.
Thanks for your help!

Make sure the registers for PGA are set (and read them back to make sure for some reason they didn't move while you wern't looking). Also your reference is 4.096V so for the default value of ±2.5*vref that is a ±10.24V range which my intuition tells me is probably too high and the PGA needs to be gained down.


So Now I feel silly.  @Burglups comments got me digging into a different part of the datasheet, and the subtle comments in the datasheet exposed the answer to my issue.
The data is shifted!
The LSB is on bit 30, not 32.

So taking a typical data and right shifting by 2:
0x89fc >> 2 = 0x22f7 which calculates to \$ 0x22f7 * \frac{5}{2^{14}}=2.7V\$ which matches the voltage on that pin.
Thanks for letting me talk it out and asking probing questions.
